# Pick one line to improve. Beginner efficiency code question

Tags: javascript, performance, big-o

I was given homework on BigO Notation and we are supposed to improve a set of code for each exercise but I am having trouble on the final question. For this, they want us to improve the code efficiency by changing one line of code, two at most. When I run it through VSCode, it tells me that .values does not exist on object types so I am assuming to improve efficiency, it has something to do with that line but not sure what to change.

```js
let myMovies = [
  {
      "title":"Rush Hour 2",
      "year":2001,
      "cast":[
          "Jackie Chan",
          "Chris Tucker"
      ],
      "genres":[
          "Comedy"
      ]
  },
  {
      "title":"The Safety of Objects",
      "year":2001,
      "cast":[
          "Glenn Close",
          "Dermot Mulroney",
          "Patricia Clarkson"
      ],
      "genres":[
          "Drama"
      ]
  },
  {
      "title":"Rush Hour 2",
      "year":2001,
      "cast":[
          "Jackie Chan",
          "Chris Tucker"
      ],
      "genres":[
          "Comedy"
      ]
  },
  //etc...
]


function removeDuplicates(movies) {
  
  let indexedMovies = {};

  movies.forEach( (movie) => {
      if (Object.keys(indexedMovies).indexOf(movie.title) < 0) {
          indexedMovies[movie.title] = movie;
      }
  })

  return indexedMovies.values();
}

let fixedMovies = removeDuplicates(myMovies);
```

Comment: I dunno.. for me that is bug fixing and not improving efficiency.

Comment: Yeah that's part of what I was confused on and wasn't sure how to word it lol. Cause that line looked like a bug to me at first but since the assignment is about efficiency, I wasn't sure.

Comment: Looks like duplicate elimination in O(n²) that should be O(n), but a bug slipped in, making the problem invalid (should be `Object.values(indexedMovies)` instead of `indexedMovies.values()`). The question's intention clearly is to use `indexedMovies` as a hashmap instead of iterating over the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idea is that you would take this section of code:

```
  movies.forEach( (movie) => {
      if (Object.keys(indexedMovies).indexOf(movie.title) < 0) {
          indexedMovies[movie.title] = movie;
      }
  })
```

And replace it with

```
  movies.forEach( (movie) => {
      indexedMovies[movie.title] = movie;
  })
```

Because when you do `indexedMovies[movie.title]` it will replace any existing "duplicate", so there's no need to check for it explicitly with all the code in the `if` statement, which is pretty inefficient on its own -- creating an array just to linearly search for an item in that array.

Comment: Is it kind of built in where it won't duplicate the the value set that's already copied within the object?

Comment: @ArcRiseGen if you have `a1 = {title: 'a': id: 1}` and `a2 = {title: 'a': id: 2}` then assigning `obj[a1.title] = a1` will set `obj` to `{ "a": a1 }` but if you then also execute `obj[a2.title] = a2`  will replace property `a` of `obj` with the object `a2`   So the key's won't be duplicated (there's only one entry for `a`) but the property value itself will now refer to the other object (`a2` which has the same title, but may be different in other ways, and is not strictly the [same object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** There is no need to search for existing movie title as

```
Object.keys(indexedMovies).indexOf(movie.title) < 0
```

since it will take O(n) and increase the complexity, You can directly check for existence as(if you want to)

```
!indexedMovies[movie.title]
```

Any even you can eliminate this process and directly assign `movie`

```
 indexedMovies[movie.title] = movie;
```

**2)** There is not such method on `values()` on `indexedMovies` object. Either return `indexedMovies` object or its values as

```
Object.values(indexedMovies)
```

```js
let myMovies = [{
    title: "Rush Hour 2",
    year: 2001,
    cast: ["Jackie Chan", "Chris Tucker"],
    genres: ["Comedy"],
  },
  {
    title: "The Safety of Objects",
    year: 2001,
    cast: ["Glenn Close", "Dermot Mulroney", "Patricia Clarkson"],
    genres: ["Drama"],
  },
  {
    title: "Rush Hour 2",
    year: 2001,
    cast: ["Jackie Chan", "Chris Tucker"],
    genres: ["Comedy"],
  },
  //etc...
];

function removeDuplicates(movies) {
  let indexedMovies = {};

  movies.forEach((movie) => indexedMovies[movie.title] = movie);

  return Object.values(indexedMovies);
}

let fixedMovies = removeDuplicates(myMovies);
console.log(fixedMovies);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still learning BigO notation but wasn't sure if replacing the Object.keys line would increase efficiency in terms of BigO.